# Intercept and read data before reaching the dotnet core ASP controllers

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, request

I have a standard asp dotnet core rest api application.
I want to read the data from the body before it arrives in the controllers to create a generic validation on that data.

I accept that I have to do this in Startup.cs, but I haven't found something similar for what I need.

STARTUP.CS

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                    var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (ex != null)
                    {
                        //var err = $"<h1>Erro: {ex.Error.Message + "<br><br>" + ex.Error.InnerException + "<br><br>" + ex.Error.StackTrace}</h1>";
                        var err = $"<p>Erro: {ex.Error.Message} </p>";
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(err, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        //await context.Response.WriteAsync(err).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                });
            });
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) 
            .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked [middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: "generic validation on that data". if you are talking about model validation then you don't need to read the data. if you need to have simple validation then just decorate your model with relevant attributes and you need little advance validation then you can think of using **fluentvalidation** nuget library.

Answer (score 1):

`I want to read the data from the body before it arrives in the controllers to create a generic validation on that data` it sounds like you want to have an [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#action-filters). After creating the filter, pls [inject the dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution) into Startup.cs file.

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add<MySampleActionFilter>();
});
```

For example, I have an .net 6 api application, I created a filter like below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace WebApiNet6
{
    public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // Do something before the action executes.
            var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // Do something after the action executes.
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed my Program.cs from `builder.Services.AddControllers()` to

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<MyActionFilter>();
});
```

Then add a break point in the filter, when I call the api, it will go into the filter before go into the controller.